# Are captureless lambdas structural types?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

[P1907R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html), accepted for C++20, introduced *structural types*, which are a valid types for non-type template parameter.

GCC and Clang both accepts the following snippet for C++2a:

```
template<auto v>
constexpr auto identity_v = v;

constexpr auto l1 = [](){};
constexpr auto l2 = identity_v<l1>;
```

implying that the type of a captureless lambda is a structural type.

#### Question

- Does a captureless lambda indeed fulfill the requirements for its type to to be a structural type?

Comment: As has been the case also for some previous occasions, my honest question ended up being answered by myself, during the process of writing it out in a thorough manner.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62324050/can-lambdas-be-used-as-non-type-template-parameter

Comment: @AmirKirsh thanks, I see I actually commented on that particular answer. The key that was missing for me (when I wrote up this question) was whether the destructor of a captureless lambda is constexpr or not, which is a requirement for its closure type to be a literal type (a requirement that is not covered in linked answer). I found this guarantee via the (indirection?) that **A)** a _defaulted destructor_ is constexpr if it can be, and **B)** that implicitly defined destructors fall under the umbrella term of defaulted destructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the resolution of defect report [CWG2542](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2542), lambdas—regardless of being captureless—are now explicitly defined **not** to be of structural type and can therefore not be used as NTTPs. This means that compilers could implement [CWG2542](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2542) at any point and reject C++20 (or newer) code that tries to use any type of lambda as an NTTP.

The relevant passage of 7.5.5.2 ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#3)) paragraph 3 will now read as:

> The closure type is not an aggregate type ([[dcl.init.aggr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr)) and not a
> structural type ([[temp.param]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#term.structural.type)).

Answer (score 7):

<sub>*All standard references below, unless explicitly noted otherwise, refers to [N4861 (March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/).*</sub>

---

#### Prior to CWG 2542, it was unclear/underspecified whether the type of a captureless lambda (its *closure type*) is a *structural type*

As highlighted in [@303's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77555156/4573247), [CWG 2542](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2542), posted 2 years after this initial Q&A, highlighted that the results of not specifying certain details of lambdas results in it being unclear whether the type of a lambda can even be a structural type or not.

- The resolution of CWG 2542 makes it clear that lambdas are **not** structural types.

This answer is kept to show the full details which shed light on the structural type-uncertainty prior to the resolution of CWG 2542.

---

Henceforth, we will refer to the type of the lambda solely as the *closure type*.

As shown through the standard passages below, the closure type of a captureless lambda fulfills the requirements for it to be a *literal (class) type*. However, prior to CWG 2542, it was underspecified as to whether it fulfilled the requirements to be a *structural type*.

Consequently, as per the standard prior to CWG 2542, the example snippet

> ```
> template<auto v>
> constexpr auto identity_v = v;
>
> constexpr auto l1 = [](){};
> constexpr auto l2 = identity_v<l1>;
> ```

may or may not be well-formed, depending on how an implementor chooses to implement the underlying closure type.

---

### The closure type of a lambda is a non-union class type

As governed by [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#1) [**emphasis** mine]

> The type of a *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) **is a unique, unnamed non-union class type**, called the closure type, whose properties are described below.

the closure type is a *non-union class type*.

---

### The closure type of a captureless lambda is a literal (class) type

As governed by [[basic.types]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.types#10) [extract, **emphasis** mine]

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>
> - [...]
> - a possibly cv-qualified **class type** that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - **it has a constexpr destructor** ([dcl.constexpr]),
>   - **it is** either **a closure type** ([expr.prim.lambda.closure]), an aggregate type ([dcl.init.aggr]), or has at least one constexpr
>     constructor or constructor template (possibly inherited from a base
>     class) that is not a copy or move constructor,
>   - if it is a union, at least one of its non-static data members is of non-volatile literal type, and
>   - **if it is not a union, all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.**

the closure type is a literal type if

- has a constexpr destructor, and if
- all of its non-static data members are of non-volatile literal types.

The closure type of a captureless lambda has no non-static data members, so the latter requirement is fulfilled. What about the former, a constexpr destructor?

#### Implicitly generated constexpr destructor

As governed by [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#14)

> The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has an implicitly-declared destructor ([class.dtor]).

the destructor of the closure type is declared implicitly. Furthermore, [[/dcl.fct.def.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def.default#5) describes [extract, **emphasis** mine]

> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions **are collectively called *defaulted* functions**, and the implementation **shall provide implicit definitions for them** ([class.ctor], **[class.dtor]**, [class.copy.ctor], [class.copy.assign]), [...]

that the collective term *defaulted* functions also include implicitly-declared destructors.

Finally, [[class.dtor]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.dtor#9)

> A defaulted destructor is a constexpr destructor if it satisfies the requirements for a constexpr destructor ([dcl.constexpr]).

describe that defaulted destructors are constexpr destructors if they fulfill the requirements of [[dcl.constexpr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr), particularly [[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#3) and [[dcl.constexpr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.constexpr#5) [extracts, **emphasis** mine]

> **[dcl.constexpr]/3** The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - [...]
> - **if the function is a** constructor or **destructor**, its class shall not have any virtual base classes;
> - [...]
>
> **[dcl.constexpr]/5** The definition of a constexpr destructor whose *function-body* is not `= delete` shall additionally satisfy the following requirement:
>
> - for every subobject of class type or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, that class type shall have a constexpr destructor.

all of which are fulfilled for the closure type of a captureless lambda (no base classes, and no subobjects; see [[intro.object]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.object#2) for the latter).

Thus, the closure type of captureless lambda is a literal type.

---

### UNDERSPECIFIED: The closure type of a captureless lambda is or is not a structural type?

As per [[temp.param]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#6) and [[temp.param]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#7) [extract, **emphasis** mine]

> **[temp.param]/6** A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (possibly cv-qualified) types:
>
> - a structural type (see below),
> - [...]
>
> **[temp.param]/7**
>
> A *structural type* is one of the following:
>
> - a scalar type, or
> - an lvalue reference type, or
> - a **literal class type with the following properties**:
>
>   - all base classes and non-static data members are public and non-mutable and
>   - the types of all bases classes and non-static data members are structural types or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof.

a literal class type is trivially a structural type if it has no base classes and no private or protected non-static data members. Whilst the first of this holds, it is nowhere specified of that the closure type of a lambda may not have any protected or private non-static data members. Thus, it cannot be read out from the standard whether the closure type of a captureless lambda is a structural type or not, as an implementor is formally allowed to implement the closure type with some internal private non-static data members.

---

### Some notes on the original *intent* of allowing the closure type of a lambda to be a literal type

[N4487](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) proposed allowing certain lambda-expressions and operations on certain closure objects to appear within constant expressions, and contained a dedicated section to the topic of a closure type being a literal type:

> #### The closure object should be a literal type if the type of each of its data­ members is a literal type.
>
> A closure type in C++14 can never be a literal type – even if all its
> data members are literal types – because it lacks a constexpr
> constructor that is not a copy or move constructor. If such a closure
> type was allowed to have an implicitly defined default constructor it
> would be constexpr, making it a literal type. But, because closure
> types, by definition, must have their default constructors deleted,
> the implementation is prohibited from implicitly defining one. [...]

[P0170R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0170r1.pdf), containing the core wording from N4487, was accepted and implemented for C++17.

At this time (C++14 and C++17), however, a destructor could not be constexpr, and thus there naturally existed no requirement for a literal type to have a constexpr destructor; [[basic.types]/10.5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.types#10.5.1) in N4140 (C++14) as well as [[basic.types]/10.5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#10.5.1) in N4659 (C++17) instead required destructor to be trivial:

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> - [...]
> - a class type (Clause [class]) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - [...]

[P1907R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html), accepted for C++20, expanded the requirement for *template parameter objects* to have constant destruction; [[temp.param]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#8) [**emphasis** mine]:

> An *id-expression* naming a non-type *template-parameter* of class type `T` denotes a static storage duration object of type `const T`, known as a *template parameter object*, whose value is that of the corresponding template argument after it has been converted to the type of the *template-parameter*. All such template parameters in the program of the same type with the same value denote the same template parameter object. [...] **A template parameter object shall have constant destruction.**

and, [P0784R7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0784r7.html), also accepted for C++20, particularly contained the introduction of constexpr destruction, including the update to the requirement for a type to be a literal type; particularly described in an earlier version of the paper, [P0784R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0784r1.html):

> The proposed rules for constexpr destructors are:
>
> - [...]
> - A literal type requires a constexpr destructor (previously, the stronger requirement of a trivial destructor was made)

Comment: How do you establish that a captureless lambda has no non-static data members?  (Not that it *should*…)

Comment: @David Herring: I agree it should not, but it's a good question; [\[expr.prim.lambda.closure\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2) is the closest I've found: _"An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this **does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than** by changing: ..."_, but t.b.h. it feels weaker than what I would hope for (given the intent of the accepted proposals that relates to constexpr/literal type lambdas). Any thoughts?

Comment: I don’t think it’s specified (even without that explicit implementation latitude).  Neither do we know the access of capture members (which doesn’t matter otherwise since they don’t have names), so even lambdas with certain *init-capture*s might be structural as well!  A proposal is probably needed if this use case is at all important.

Comment: @DavisHerring I see, thanks. Whilst this is possibly a gap in the normative text, the intent of the related, accepted proposals (e.g. N4487: _"... if the initialization of **all of its data members** (that correspond **to each capture**)"_) and other related normative segments ([expr.prim.lambda.capture/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture#12): _"[...]  additional unnamed non-static data members [...] If declared, such non-static data members **shall be of literal type.**"_) arguably seems to imply that additional non-static data members should not be ...

Comment: ... allowed to affect whether the closure type is a literal (and as of C++20: structural) type or not.

Comment: Being a structural type is a much stronger requirement than being a literal type, so it’s not much help that some “additional” members are guaranteed to have the latter property.  I’m not arguing with the “most reasonable interpretation” being as you say, but it’s important to know that there’s no guarantee (yet?).

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks, I will update my self-answer tomorrow with this discussion.