# Is a lambda expression a legal default (non-type template) argument?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4861 (March 2020 post-Prague working draft/C++20 DIS)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/).*</sub>

---

#### Background

The Q&A [Are captureless lambdas structural types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461199/are-captureless-lambdas-structural-types) highlighted the potential underspecification of whether certain lambda-expressions have associated closure types that are (literal and) structural types or not. The impact of this classification could allow or reject using a closure type as non-type template parameter; essentially passing structural type lambdas as non-type template parameters.

> ```
> template<auto v>
> constexpr auto identity_v = v;
>
> constexpr auto l1 = [](){};
> constexpr auto l2 = identity_v<l1>;
> ```

Now, according to [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#1) the type *of each lambda-expression* is unique

> [...] a **unique**, unnamed non-union class type, called the *closure type* [...]

On the other hand, [[basic.def.odr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#1) [extract, **emphasis** mine] states

> No translation unit shall contain more than **one definition of any** variable, function, class type, enumeration type, template, default argument for a parameter (for a function in a given scope), or **default template argument**.

arguably meaning that default template arguments are considered definitions that need to respect the ODR.

#### Question

... which leads to my question:

- Is a lambda expression a legal default (non-type template) argument and, if so, wouldn't this imply that each instantiation using such a default argument instantiates a unique specialization?

(Please highlight also if near-illegal: e.g. if anything beyond a single instantiation would lead to an ODR-violation).

---

#### Why?

If this is in fact legal, each invocation of say a variable template with a lambda as default argument would result in an instantiation of a unique specialization:

```
template<auto l = [](){}>
               // ^^^^^^ - lambda-expression as default argument
constexpr auto default_lambda = l;

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<
    decltype(default_lambda<>),
    decltype(default_lambda<>)>);
```

Both GCC ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BuWIZHfpxKyXY6qw)) and Clang ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/amg57ssI3my8toVI)) accepts the program above

If the compilers are correct to accept this example, this means allowing another mechanism to capture and retrieve a meta-programming state, a technique that has since long been deemed, as per [CWG open issue 2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118), as

> ... arcane and should be made ill-formed.

Comment: **[temp.decls]/2** is about default *function* arguments (a la `void foo(int = 0);`). It doesn't apply to default template arguments. The standard uses "default template-argument" when appropriate to be exact, it intentionally avoids sloppy use of the term.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks, I updated to refer to [\[basic.def.odr\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#1) instead, which describes (however in a weaker sense/indirectly) that default template arguments are definitions.

Comment: I believe that [this motion](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3070/commits/02f1104e765e9adfcc7bbc449428a66d7213cc1a) addressed this issue, but I barely understand that standard wording.

Comment: @metalfox I may be mistaken, but that seems to related to [CWG issue 2300](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2300) which particularly relates to default function parameter arguments, and not default template arguments. A default template argument would imply instantiations refer to _different_ specializations (as the closure type is embedded in the specialization), whereas a default function parameter argument means we could have _different function definitions_ for _the same specialization_, thus violating ODR.

Comment: Why do you think that such a default template argument would be “evaluated” at each usage to produce a different type?  The corresponding rule about default (function) arguments is about *run-time* behavior.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm more wondering than thinking, based on that A) GCC makes this interpretation (as shown in my example above; is this a GCC bug?), and B) [basic.def.odr]/13, particularly [\[basic.odr.def\]/13.13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#13.13): _"In each such [template entity] definition, [...] a default template arg used by a template-[..] is treated as if its token sequence were present in the definition of `D`; that is, [...] **the default template argument is subject to the requirements described in this paragraph (recursively).**"_, emphasis on recursively.

Comment: ... [\[basic.def.odr\]/13.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.def.odr#13.6) explicitly mentions that there can be more than one definition of default template arguments. For a lambda-expression used as a default template argument (if this is even legal?), would the expression be evaluated anew for two instantiations in different TU:s, or is it pre-defined even before any instantiation? If so, where would such a single definition belong? If we ever have two different evaluations of the lambda-expression, we arguably have two different associated closure types. ...

Comment: ... Finally, [\[temp.arg\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg#8) describe that the default template argument is instantiated (instantiated?) _"when the value of that default argument **is needed**"_; I don't really follow how this controls _when_ say a default argument lambda-expression is "instantiated" (the wording used in \[temp.arg\]/8), and moreover what it would mean w.r.t. where its definition belong (and whether there can be several, different definitions of different closure types). T.b.h. I'm beat by the standardese in this context, hence this question.

Comment: The newest MSVC version accepts your code, too.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13.10
looks interesting

Comment: @Bernd I did read that paragraph before, but didn't really know how to interpret it. But looking at it again, maybe this implicitly **allows** lambda-expressions as default template arguments _and_ explicitly notes that these will have different closure types (and thus definitions) for each instantiation of the templated entity? I still feel like I'm on speculating ground for the latter, though.

Comment: I think that because lambdas without captures are now trivial types like structs without members, lambdas can be passed like them as template parameters. I am not shure about a possible ODR violation. Those might lead to multiple instanciations of the template, where only one is expected.

Comment: hm, template can be declared only in scope where lambda expression can be only captureless, so nothing "arcane"  happens?

Comment: Lambda's closure type does not need to be structural in order to capture and retrieve a metaprogramming state. Indeed, since [p0315r2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r2.pdf) lambdas can now appear in unnevaluated contexts:
```cpp
template <typename T = decltype([]{})> 
constexpr auto foo = T{};  

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(foo<>), decltype(foo<>)>);
```

Comment: I think it was a mistake to make lambdas unique random types. Perhaps capture types plus the implementation should have determined lambda type instead. This way lambdas with the same implementation would have the same type.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I think not making them unique would open up a can of ODR-worms for compiler implementors as well as general C++ developers, but I agree that these side effects of this design can be suprising.

Comment: @dfrib those worms commonly referred as spaghettis. Yet, a year and some later there is still no clear answer about if this is legal, intentional and how it should work..

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I guess I could bring it to one of the reflectors to see if anyone can provide a clear answer there. As David Herring points out in comments to [the linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461199/are-captureless-lambdas-structural-types), there may not be any actual standard guarantee that captureless lambas are structural types.

Comment: @dfrib lambdas are. The difference of  capturless one is that it got a defined conversion operator - and that's where implementations with several implicit call conventions may fail to be compliant, because there is no implicit conversion possible. Oh, and about ODR-use? I guess "defined by an identical set of lexems" may apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it is not a legal default non-type template argument, as the closure type of lambdas are, as per the resolution of [CWG 2542](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2542), not structural types.

> #### 2542. Is a closure type a structural type?
>
> Consider:
>
> ```
> template <auto V>
> void foo() {}
>
> void bar() {
>   foo<[i = 3] { return i; }>();
> }
> ```
>
> It is unclear whether the data members of a closure type are public or
> private. This makes a difference, since it affects whether a closure
> type is a structural type or not [...]
>
> [...]
>
> **Proposed resolution (approved by CWG 2023-03-30):**
>
> Change in 7.5.5.2 [expr.prim.lambda.closure] paragraph 2 as follows:
>
> > ... The closure type is not an aggregate type (9.4.2 [dcl.init.aggr]) **and not a structural type** (13.2 [temp.param]).
> > ...

Comment: To be honest, the DR's motivation is a bit lame. It's also very weird they decided to go against existing implementations, considering structural types are defined in such a way so that implementations are feasible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a lambda expression a legal default (non-type template) argument and, if so, wouldn't this imply that each instantiation using such a default argument instantiates a unique specialization?

Yes, it means that given your templated variable:

```cpp
template<auto l = [](){}>
constexpr auto default_lambda = l;
```

every call to `default_lambda` will produce a new template instantiation by generating a new unique closure type and thus provides a new way to capture a metaprogramming state.

Thus, every expressions that use `default_lambda` have to be reevaluated. If the state of the compiler changed since the last instantiation and if we used it in a dependent expression (ex: check that a type is defined) then the result of the expression might change.
For example:

```cpp
struct X; // not defined

template <typename T, auto = default_lambda<>>
consteval bool is_defined() {
    if constexpr (requires { T{}; }) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

static_assert(is_defined<X>() == false);

struct X {};
static_assert(is_defined<X>() == true);
```

Comment: Whilst the consteval example is interesting, this only repeats what is already observed in the question: that compilers _seems_ to treat each instantiation as a unique specialization. What I’m looking for, emphasized my the language-lawyer tag of my question, is a normative reference to provide a definite answer. For these types of outlier topics, what the compilers implement may not actually be what the standard says, and the observed behavior may particularly be only by coincidence or even apparently well-behaving ill-formed NDR.

Comment: The sections you quoted seem to indicate that this behavior is well formed.