# At which point are default template arguments instantiated in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20, default-arguments

Since every lambda expression in C++ has a unique closure type, and this type can be used as the default argument of a template parameter (since C++20, using `decltype`), it is important to know at which point that type is instantiated. Consider this C++20 example:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template<typename T = decltype([]{})>
using X = T;

template<typename T = X<>>
auto foo() { return T{}; }

int main() {
    using T1 = decltype(foo());
    using T2 = decltype(foo());
    static_assert(!std::same_as<T1, T2>);
}
```

Here, the default argument of the template parameter `T` in the definition of type alias `X` is the closure type `decltype([]{})`. The function template `foo()` has this as its return type.

If the instantiation of new closure type takes place every time `foo()` appears in the program, then the types `T1` and `T2` must be distinct, as the `static_assert`ion passes. However, this assertion passes only when compiling with GCC.

For clang and MSVC, the types `T1` and `T2` are the same, meaning that instantiation of the default argument doesn't take place every time (but rather once, at the template declaration). See [Compiler Explorer demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dzYjf9r3q).

Which compiler is compliant with the standard?

Comment: @NicolBolas This question is tagged language-lawyer, though, meaning the OPs' are typically intentionally interested in these kind of language details, either due to a puzzle interest or a more legitimate one, neither one invalidating these kind of questions. This particular question is very related to (and possible a duplicate of) the unanswered [Is a lambda expression a legal default (non-type template) argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464147/is-a-lambda-expression-a-legal-default-non-type-template-argument).

Comment: @NicolBolas: you are right of course. But I cannot refrain to remember the good old days when C++ was presented as an attempt to add some security to C by avoiding many UB use cases. I now have a strong feeling that there are  more UB risk in C++  than in C due to its complexity. Of course when you write code from scratch, it is easy to only use parts of the standard that you know well, but maintaining someone else's code can lead to nightmares...

Comment: ... To go closer to the question, I am afraid that this is just one of the underspecified points of C++. As the language is now very complex, there are more and more of them. So I agree with you on one point that is explicit in a note about UB (ref n4860 draft, [defns.undefined], Note 1): *Undefined behavior may be expected when this document omits any explicit definition of behavior...*. If it is not explicit in the standard, programmers should not even try to guess what could happen.

Comment: [These two cases are interesting](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7hsMWqsbx); here I made the lambda type dependent or not on another template parameter, and when it *was* dependent MSVC/clang made it always the same type, and when it *wasn't* the type was unique for each call.

Comment: I believe MSVC is just broken, and the default `T` in `X`'s declaration is evaluated only once, so `X<>` always resolves to the same type (example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WYaKzadj3)

Comment: Maybe it depends on what the compiler turns a lambda into (actually into a class). I mean, that maybe compiler for every foo() call generate different lambda classes in some cases

Comment: I see only one lambda expression (in the decltype) so "the lambda expression (has) a unique type" does not require T1 and T2 to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that this is an under-specified area of the standard. Default template arguments are simply assumed to have a "value", but it is unclear whether this is a single value, or whether each each use of a default-template argument is meant to produce a new instance of this value.

While the standard is unclear on whether your assertion should pass or not, lambda expressions in default template arguments are an ODR footgun waiting to happen. The details are explained below.

### The Long Answer

To dissect this, let's start at the call sites, namely the two occurrences of `decltype(foo())`. These are using function template argument deduction, so what happens is:

> When all template arguments have been deduced or obtained from default template arguments, all uses of template parameters in the template parameter list of the template are replaced with the corresponding deduced or default argument values.

- [[temp.deduct.general] §5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.general#5)

This means that `decltype(foo())` is translated into `decltype(foo<X<>>())`. This is the main point of ambiguity, because it is not stated whether "value" refers the type `X<>` or to the symbols comprising `X<>`. I.e., it is unclear whether the compiler is allowed to perform memoization like `decltype(foo<__X_instantiation>())`.

Now we have to deal with `X<>`, which is a *simple-template-id*:

> When a *simple-template-id* does not name a function, a *default template-argument* is implicitly instantiated when the value of that default argument is needed.
>
> *[Example 7:*
>
> ```cpp
> template<typename T, typename U = int> struct S { };
> S<bool>* p;         // the type of p is S<bool, int>*
> ```
>
> The default argument for U is instantiated to form the type `S<bool, int>*`. *- end example]*

- [[temp.arg.general] §9](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.general#9)

This means that we form the expression `decltype(foo<X<decltype([]{})>>)`, where the template arguments of `foo` are possibly memoized. As for where `[]{}` is declared:

> 1. The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the closure type, whose properties are described below.
> 2. The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

- [[expr.prim.lambda.closure] §1, §2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#1)

If the compiler was allowed to perform memoization of `X<>`, then we would see the following code after:

- function template argument deduction
- default template argument instantiation
- instantation of templates at the points described in [[temp.point]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point)

```cpp
struct closure { /* ... */ };

// The expression in decltype is not type-dependent, so decltype(closure{})
// would NOT denote a new unique type.
// The same applies to all uses of decltype in this problem.
template<typename T = decltype(closure{})>
using X = T;

using __X_instantiation = X<decltype(closure{})>; // = closure

template<typename T = __X_instantiation>
auto foo() { return T{}; }

int main() {
    using T1 = decltype(foo<decltype(__X_instantiation{})>()); // = closure
    using T2 = decltype(foo<decltype(__X_instantiation{})>()); // = closure
    /* ... */
}

template auto foo<__X_instantiation>() { return __X_instantiation{}; }
```

Otherwise, we would end up with:

```cpp
/* ... */

int main() {
    struct closure1 { /* ... */ };
    using T1 = decltype(foo<X<decltype(closure1{})>>()); // = closure1
    struct closure2 { /* ... */ };
    using T1 = decltype(foo<X<decltype(closure2{})>>()); // = closure2
    /* ... */
}

template auto foo<X<closure1>>() { return closure1{}; }
template auto foo<X<closure2>>() { return closure2{}; }
```

It is unclear which of these is correct, and depends on whether the implementation chooses memoization of `X<>`. This is implemented differently from compiler to compiler, which is why your `static_assert(!std::same_as<T1, T2>)` passes for some, but not for others.

### ODR-Violation Just Waiting To Happen

Note that `X` is a massive footgun, because it is ill-formed if you include `X` in multiple translation units:

```cpp
template<typename T = decltype([]{})>
using X = T;
```

In [basic.def.odr], we see the disaster unfold:

> [...] a default template argument used by an (implicit or explicit) template-id or simple-template-id is treated as if its token sequence were present in the definition of [a template] `D`; that is, the default argument or default template argument is subject to the requirements described in this paragraph (recursively).

- [[basic.def.odr] §14.11](https://eel.is/c++draft/full#basic.def.odr-14.11)

This means, that when we use `X<>`, it is as if we wrote:

```cpp
template<typename T = __default_arg>
using X = T, /* and declare */ __default_arg = decltype([]{});
```

*Note: obviously this is not legal C++, it's just meant to illustrate where the default template argument is considered to be for ODR purposes.*

> If `D` is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit, [...]
> These requirements also apply to corresponding entities defined **within each definition of `D`** ([...]).
> For each such entity and for `D` itself, the behavior is **as if there is a single entity with a single definition**, including in the application of these requirements to other entities.

- [[basic.def.odr] §15](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#15)

Because the default argument is treated as if it was inside `X`, these ODR restrictions apply, and the behavior is as if there was one definition of `decltype([]{})`. However, because we declare a new closure type with each lambda expression, that is an ODR-violation just waiting to happen:

> ```cpp
> /* [...] */
> inline void g(bool cond, void (*p)() = []{}) {
>   if (cond) g(false);
> }
> /* [... ] */
> ```
>
> [...] If the definition of `g` appears in multiple translation units, **the program is ill-formed (no diagnostic required)** because each such definition uses a default argument that refers to a distinct lambda-expression closure type. [...]

- [[basic.def.odr] §16](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#16)

The above example equally applies to `decltype([]{})` in template parameters, as the same rules in regards to the One-Definition Rule apply.

*Note: None of these rules help us disambiguate the question code, because they only apply if templates appear in multiple translation units.*

Answer (score -3):

lambdas are just functor structs. This syntax sugar is resolve right on the top, before even the optimization passes take place.

I have changed the assert to make the code compile.  If you apply this code to [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=CiNpbmNsdWRlIDxjb25jZXB0cz4KCnRlbXBsYXRlPHR5cGVuYW1lIFQgPSBkZWNsdHlwZShbXXt9KT4KdXNpbmcgWCA9IFQ7Cgp0ZW1wbGF0ZTx0eXBlbmFtZSBUID0gWDw+PgphdXRvIGZvbygpIHsgcmV0dXJuIFR7fTsgfQoKaW50IG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICB1c2luZyBUMSA9IGRlY2x0eXBlKGZvbygpKTsKICAgIHVzaW5nIFQyID0gZGVjbHR5cGUoZm9vKCkpOwogICAgc3RhdGljX2Fzc2VydChzdGQ6OnNhbWVfYXM8VDEsIFQyPik7Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp2b,alt-syntax-for,alt-syntax-subscription,all-implicit-casts,use-libcpp,edu-show-initlist,edu-show-noexcept,edu-show-padding&std=cpp2b&rev=1.0) you can see that the types resolve to the single struct type.

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T = decltype([]{})>
using X = T;

template<typename T = __lambda_4_32>
auto foo()
{
  return T{};
}


#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
__lambda_4_32 foo<__lambda_4_32>()
{
  return __lambda_4_32{};
}
#endif


int main()
{
  using T1 = __lambda_4_32;
  using T2 = __lambda_4_32;
  /* PASSED: static_assert(std::same_as<__lambda_4_32, __lambda_4_32>); */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cppinsights itself can be wrong. Normally `language-lawyer` questions are expected to be answered with a quote from the standard.

Answer (score -3):

*Although the question was answered, I decided to clean up my answer according to valuable comments.*

1. [[dcl.typedef]#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef#1.sentence-6): (Note that `using` has the same effect as `typedef`.)

   > [...] A *typedef-name* does not introduce a new type [...]

   Thus, `std::same_as<T1, T2>` effectively becomes `std::same_as<decltype(foo()), decltype(foo())>`.
2. [[basic.def.odr]#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2):

   > No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any definable item.

   Where [definable item [basic.def.odr]#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) is:

   > Each of the following is termed a *definable item*:
   >
   > - [...]
   > - **a default template argument** ([[temp.param]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param)).

   Every specialization of function template `foo()` using default argument in `typename T = X<>`, they all have the *same* `X<>`, according to One-definition rule.
3. [[dcl.type.decltype] #1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.sentence-2):

   > The operand of `decltype` is an **unevaluated operand**.

   And [[dcl.type.decltype] #2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#2.sentence-1):

   > If the operand of a *decltype-specifier* is a **prvalue** and is **not a (possibly parenthesized) immediate invocation** ([expr.const](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#def:immediate_invocation)), the temporary materialization conversion is not applied ([conv.rval](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rval)) and no result object is provided for the prvalue.

   `foo()` in `decltype(foo())` expression is a prvalue and is not an immediate invocation, so `decltype(foo())` becomes *same* `X<>`.

   So the assertion becomes `!std::same_as<X<>, X<>>`, where the two `X<>` are the same, which should fail.

Comment: cppreference can be wrong, and sometimes is. It shouldn't be used to answer language-lawyer questions. Instead, refer to the C++ standard. Your own experiments with `typeid` can only tell you how compilers implement these mechanics, but they don't answer fundamental language questions. Compilers are also not perfectly standard-compliant, and may be wrong.