# Errors from nested templated lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

GCC considers the following piece of code as ill-formed where as clang produces an internal compiler error.

```cpp
template <auto V1 = []{ return 0; }>
struct s {
    template <auto V2 = []{ return V1(); }>
    consteval int foo() { return V2(); }
};

int main() {
    return s{}.foo(); // error
}
```

---

Is this code valid according the standard ?

Comment: Yep. Submitted [102644](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102644) for gcc.

Comment: Related: [Is a lambda expression a legal default (non-type template) argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464147). @Barry: As asked in the linked to open question: given that closure types are unique, is it well-defined in C++20 whether two "subsequent" instantiations that leverage a lambda expression as a default template argument produce the same specialization or not? Both GCC and Clang seems to say "different specializations", and both treats (ignoring the member function template above for GCC) `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<s<>,s<>>);` as well-formed.

Comment: @dfrib I would expect them to be different types yeah.

Comment: @Barry Would that not open up the can of worms of capturing meta-programming states even more than what is already highlighted in [CWG open issue 2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118)?

Comment: There is a post on wether statetul metaprogramming with templated lambdas is well-formed or not https://stackoverflow.com/q/64464147 I have also seen some projects using it https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr-cpp20