Are repeated declarations of a template with a type-template-parameter defaulted to a closure type a violation of ODR?
Since C++20 gave us lambdas in unevaluated context, I can write the following code.
template <class = decltype([]{})>
class MyType {};

If I were to include this definition in multiple TUs, would it be an ODR violation?
I'm looking in particular at §6.3(13.13) of N4860:

In each such definition, [...] a default
template argument used by an (implicit or explicit) template-id or simple-template-id is treated as if its
token sequence were present in the definition of D; that is, the default argument or default template
argument is subject to the requirements described in this paragraph (recursively).

which I read as, decltype([]{}) is part of the declared type, which is then an example explicitly labeled as invalid by the original paper (§4). Am I reading this correctly?
Edit 1: here's another quote from the same paragraph of the standard which I find very confusing:

There can be more than one definition of a
[...]
(13.4) — templated entity (13.1),
[...]
(13.6) — default template argument
in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit and the definitions satisfy
the following requirements. Given such an entity D defined in more than one translation unit, for all definitions
of D, [...] the following requirements shall be satisfied.
[...]
(13.10) — In each such definition, except within the default arguments and default template arguments of D,
corresponding lambda-expressions shall have the same closure type (see below).

Now, we can apply this paragraph to my code snippet above eithera) by taking D to be the class template (which is a templated entity), in which case (13.10) seems to say the default template argument is exempt from this rule, orb) by taking D to be the default template argument, to which this rule must be applied. The "see below" at the end of the quote refers to, I presume, point 14:

If D is a template and is defined in more than one translation unit, then the preceding requirements shall
apply both to names from the template’s enclosing scope used in the template definition (13.8.3), and also
to dependent names at the point of instantiation (13.8.2). These requirements also apply to corresponding
entities defined within each definition of D (including the closure types of lambda-expressions, but excluding
entities defined within default arguments or default template arguments of either D or an entity not defined
within D). For each such entity and for D itself, the behavior is as if there is a single entity with a single
definition, including in the application of these requirements to other entities. [Note: The entity is still
declared in multiple translation units, and 6.6 still applies to these declarations. In particular, lambda-expressions (7.5.5) appearing in the type of D may result in the different declarations having distinct types,
and lambda-expressions appearing in a default argument of D may still denote different types in different
translation units. — end note]

from which I understand: if D is my template class, the default template argument is exempt from this rule. But then the note at the end goes on to specify that the lambda-expression in the default template argument might have different types in different TUs, hence, I presume, breaking ODR.
Edit 2: very much related, but I can't seem to get to a final conclusion still:Meaning of note about multiply defined itemsDo lambda expressions that appear in different definitions of a same entity produce the same closure type?

Considering reading 3. Every instantiation is a unique type (on each "source" line the lambda will have a new unique type).

I don't have a standard ref to back me but my experiments are showing the behavior described by @PepijnKramer: each instantiation gives a different type with clang. But cppinsight does not seem to agree: https://cppinsights.io/s/3e743593.

Also I haven't looked up the final wording in the standard, which might differ yet again. So it can still be cppinsights is right

I guess you have found a case to file DR. IMO default argument should be deduced at instantiation point, rather than definition. That allows lambdas to have different types. But even then, a type aliase to an instance of template can be source of debate.

Side note : I do not see a direct use case for this feature, or even worse with the wording as it is. I just see using this construct as an accident waiting to happen and I would happily look for another construct to solve my issue (if I had any)

@Jarod42 isn't there a copy-paste error in your example? I propose this

@Oersted: copy paste error indeed, comment removed.

And so cppinsight shows wrongly /* PASSED: static_assert(!std::is_same_v<MyType<__lambda_3_28>, MyType<__lambda_3_28> >); */ Demo

@PepijnKramer msvc also produces variables of different types at each instantiation, and I believe that to be the correct behavior.

@PepijnKramer I do have a use case for this "feature", but it's quite a bit more involved. Fundamentally, what I want is a "unique type generator": I would like to be able to declare globals inline MyType my_global_var = ...; in my headers and have each of them be of a different type.

for the record: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype in the example at the bottom: "The type of a lambda function is unique and unnamed"

@Red.Wave the paper for the original proposal (linked in the question) actually specifically talks about aliases in §4

@AndreaAgostini Interesting :) Though global variables? Or do you mean inline constexpr constants?

The author's own comments under this question also seem to be raising the same kind of argument: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64464147/23129286

@PepijnKramer (sighs) I do mean global variables. In my specific case, inline const, but not constexpr. Please let us not go down the "global variables are evil" path. I'm aware they are.

Then I will not ;)

Maybe I get it wrong but, if the type is different each time, you have only one definition, thus no ODR violation? It's more that, as the different TU do not communicate, the same "type id" is generated twice but they don't see each other so no problem (otherwise you couldn't work with templates at all?). The issue would be more if you want some to optimize and not instantiate several time the same code, which does not seem to be your need.

@Oersted my current understanding (I could be wrong ofc) is that ODR applies to templates too, and not just to their instantiations. This is the first point in [basic.def.odr].

There are subtleties between the definition of a template and its instanciations I think. You can write MyTemplate N times in the same TU but only the first one will trigger an actual definition. Is it correct?

@AndreaAgostini the SO link from your comment approves my first demand(evaluation on instantiation). And the SO link in OP update approves the second(ODR on alias). Although - I guess - compilers are still sloppy to catch up. But both links are good news.

@PepijnKramer the simplest use case would be to have the lambda return std::source_location::current();. Now each instance of the template has a different intel for reflection purposes. But there's more. I have a few useful use cases in mind the require some boilerplate code.

@Red.Wave Even in older C++ versions without std::source_location::current() and templatees it is possible to generate unique variable/type names using the preprocessor.  (using FILE, LINE tricks).  I am not proud but I have done those things ;)

@PepijnKramer std::source_location uses similar hacks, but once amd only in one place. The point in this thread is to inject context dependency into template instantiations, using lambdas.

Yes, you would get an ODR violation in this case, and it's usually IFNDR except in the named module case mentioned in [basic.def.odr]/15.
[basic.def.odr]/1.7 states that default template arguments are one of the kinds of definable item and [basic.def.odr]/15 requires multiple definitions of a definable item to be "the same". However, every lambda expression produces a distinct type, including the same lambda spelled the same way in two different translation units. There are situations in which a lambda has the same type across two TUs because it is part of an enclosing definition:
inline int foo() {
    return []{ return 0; }();  // same lambda in every TU
}

This is only because [basic.def.odr]/17 allows multiple definitions of a definable item to behave as if there were a single definition in the program. In the case of foo, a single definition across all TUs implies a single lambda closure type across all TUs.
Does this unification apply to the OP's class template? No, because [basic.def.odr]/17 has a carve-out for default arguments and default template arguments:

These requirements also apply to corresponding entities defined within each definition of D (including the closure types of lambda-expressions, but excluding entities defined within default arguments or default template arguments of either D or an entity not defined within D).
For each such entity and for D itself, the behavior is as if there is a single entity with a single definition, including in the application of these requirements to other entities.

Taking D as the class template MyType, we see that the default template argument for its (unnamed) template parameter is an excluded entity, so the behavior is not as if there is only a single definition of the default argument across the entire program.
On the other hand, taking D to be the default argument definition itself, we see that [basic.def.odr]/15 is violated because bullet 15.6 requires:

In each such definition, except within the default arguments and default template arguments of D, corresponding lambda-expressions shall have the same closure type (see below).

Because D in this case is the default template argument itself, it doesn't have any of its own default template arguments (D is after all not itself a template) so it can't benefit from the exception in this bullet. The lambda-expression must be the same in all definitions. Because /15 is violated, D cannot benefit from /17, it's just an ODR violation.
One of the examples in p18 uses a default function argument instead of a default template argument:
inline void g(bool cond, void (*p)() = []{}) {
  if (cond) g(false);
}

The explanatory text states that defining g in multiple TUs causes an ODR violation because each lambda has a different type. Since default function arguments are treated the same way as default template arguments for the purposes of the ODR, the OP's example was clearly intended to also be an ODR violation.

Isn't [basic.def.odr]/15.11 key to the argument of "taking D to be the default [template] argument definition itself"? If so, whilst a detail, it's looks as if it's strictly not ODR to include the MyType definition in several different TUs. It's only when more than one such TU implicitly or explicitly refers to the (primary template's "default" case) template specialization ("used by") that p15 applies? The note of p17 may also be worth visiting ("[...] and lambda-expressions appearing in a default argument of D might still denote different types in different translation units").

(FYI @AndreaAgostini) Referring to OP's niche use case, it may also be interesting to visit whether making the lambda defined as a default template argument a template itself would change things. I.e., template <class = decltype([]<class = void>{})> class MyType {};. Finally, OP: you may leverage the hack of adding a TU-local tag as an additional type template parameter the MyType, where the tag type is defined (in the same header) within an unnamed namespace (an otherwise odd anti-pattern). This still leaves the question on whether the lambda arg. is ODR-violating within a single TU.

@dfrib my point was to make tag-type-generation automatic for user-friendliness reasons. If the users of my MyType are willing to declare a tag-type to use as template argument for MyType, I don't need the lambda anymore :) Ultimately my goal was to identify a resource across dlls, so one could write struct UserTag {}; inline const MyType<UserTag> my_global_var = ...; and be done with it :)

btw Brian thank you for the very clear answer.

@dfrib The requirement of p15.11 is in addition to anything I wrote in my answer; it does not come into play when the default template argument is not used, and is therefore not applicable to the OP's situation.
